Small 12V DC motor direction
When I connect the power with alligator clips from the 12VDC transformer the motor goes in one direction. However, if I disconnect one of the clips and do not change anything (the same clip goes to the same motor lead and the 12 V transformer remains plugged in) when I reconnect the lead sometimes the motor goes in the reverse direction. It is running a small belt on plastic wheels. How can I ensure it always goes in the same direction?
UPDATE: The transformer changes 110 AC to 12V DC. The OV, grounding to V and such is way beyond me. I simply want the motor to run, for example, clockwise each time I switch it on. No leads have been changed not alligator clips switched from the same lead. Nothing is different. The motor 12VDC 3 RPM ( nice and slow) just goes counterclockwise "sometimes" when I switch it on. I hope this additional info help. The motor is a generic one, bought years ago.
Further update: To answer a question: The motor label says: reduction DC Synchronous motor, ZTJ-50 DC12V 3 RPM Miuro ?? (it's hard to read the label) Motor Co. Ltd.

what is a DC transformer?

I have heard of a DC-DC converter referred to as a "DC transformer".  But the details matter, maybe add a link to whatever you are calling a DC transformer, and the motor datasheet as well.  Otherwise, it will be hard to help.

Are you sure it isn't an AC motor?  https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2265/why-does-the-microwave-plate-start-in-a-random-direction

What type of motor is it?

Here's the manufacturer's description of the ZTJ-50 motor.
ZTJ-50 brushless reduction motor DC.12V slow speed motor turntable wheel [brushless non-directional forward and reverse rotation] slow speed motor.

Here's the data sheet.

Images courtesy : ruten.com
Its a brushless DC synchronous turntable motor, with a shaft speed of 3 RPM, requiring a 12 V DC source.
Its direction of rotation would depend on the rotor position at start.
The turntable, most probably, refers to that in a microwave oven.

If you are using a 12VDC power Supply with V+ and V- terminals, you can connect a Ground Earth Jumper into the V- to Bias the voltage in that direction.

What direction are you referring to? Grounding the V- terminal does not change the voltage applied to the motor.

Biasing the V- will bring the potential to 0V. So the V+ always sourcing only.

The motor is only going to react to the voltage between the V+ and V- terminals. Grounding the V- terminal does not affect motor operation.
